# Custom taxonomies Wordpress - display by category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have my custom post type working fine within a shortcode - and it is displaying fine without trying to filter by category. However when trying to filter by category something goes wrong heres the code I am using for the shortcode.

```
function topListing() {
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'directory_listing', 
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'order' => DESC,
            'tax_query' => array(
                           array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'things-to-do',
                                'field' => 'slug'
            )
        )
    );
query_posts($args); 
$output = "<ul>";

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $output = $output."<li>";
    $output = $output.'<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
    $output = $output.'</li>';
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();

$output = $output."</ul>";

return $output;
}

add_shortcode("homepage_listing", "topListing");
```

I have seen a lot of people having a 'terms' option with the tax_query array however I'm not sure what I would need to put in there.

Instead of pulling back all the post, I just want the post that have the categories of 'Things to do'.

Answer (score 0):

The `tax_query` [accepts a few parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters): Taxonomy, Field (slug, term_id), Terms. So if I have a taxonomy called "Colors" and a term called "Blue" and I wanted to get all posts assigned to the "Blue" Term, my `tax_query` would look something like this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'colors',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => 'blue'
    )
)
```

But in your case it sounds like you want Any and All Posts assigned to ANY term that's in a certain taxonomy. Unfortunately, WP_Query doesn't work like that, you would need to get all your terms and include them into your query like so:

```
$termArr = array();                     // Create Array to hold term slugs
$terms = get_terms('things-to-do');     // Get all terms inside taxonomy
foreach($terms as $term){                // Loop Through Terms Array
    $termArr[] = $term->slug;            // Push Term Slug into our Term Array
}

'tax_query' => array(                   // Get All Posts Assigned to These Terms
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'things-to-do',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $termArr
    )
);
```

[`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) will hide any empty terms by default, and we don't care what order they're in so we will only receive populated terms, and in the end we will get all posts assigned to any term in that certain taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where you have put 'tax_products' would I put my category slug name there?

Comment: @SamKelham That's from my testing, you would put your taxonomy name there. I've fixed it now.

Comment: still not a appearing, I have still included it into the original $args array, exactly like my original post but just with your added code, or just literally use you code without declaring the post type I'm referring to? So to be a pain, still learning the ways of PHP

Comment: When you registered your taxonomy, what did you call it? and you would want to replace your tax query with my tax query, with the `$termArr` and `foreach` declared above your `$args` variable